# Php command on Crontab and in PHP-Cli, same? (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, cron, php

I'm with a trouble in my webhost. I have a CodeIgniter php-cli Script that is running on the SSH Terminal but when I put it in Crontab does not run, gives me several errors. The most weird thing is that this php-cli Script have been running by months.

What could be the problem and how can I start to solve it?

Restart the php-cli deamon should be a start?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v2.0.0 then you will need to make sure you set the current working directory of the crontab to the level of your index.php.

Or, upgrade to v2.0.1 which will do this for you.

Remember that when you get error messages you should post them in your question, otherwise answers end up just being guesswork.

Comment: I don't have access to the error from here. In 5 hours I will post the error. I'm using CodeIgniter 1.7.2. I think I'm using a method for run CodeIgniter code in Crontab that was developed by you. Thanks for your reply. Best Regards,

Comment: I'd upgrade to 2.0.1. That old CLI code was not great and I don't think it ever supported the current working directory, meaning 2.0.1 is the only version where this will work.